# How to read in multiple lines into one array or hash until the next line fits certain criteria in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, readline, readfile

If I want to read multiple lines with same elements into one array or hash until reaching the next line with a different element. These elements have already been sorted so they are in the lines next to each other. For example:

```
1_1111  1234
1_1111  2234 
1_1111  3234
1_1112  4234
1_1112  5234
1_1112  6234
1_1112  7234
1_1113  8234
1_1113  9234
```

I want to read the first three lines with same element 1_1111 into one array, process it, then read the next few lines with the same element 1_1112

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my $key;
my @nums;
while (<>) {
   my @fields = split;
   if (@nums && $fields[0] ne $key) {
      process($key, @nums);
      @nums = ();
   }

   $key = $fields[0];
   push @nums, $fields[1];
}

process($key, @nums) if @nums;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file into a hash of arrays:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash;
while (<DATA>) {
    my ($key, $value) = split /\s+/;
    push @{ $hash{$key} }, $value;
}

__DATA__
1_1111  1234
1_1111  2234
1_1111  3234
1_1112  4234
1_1112  5234
1_1112  6234
1_1112  7234
1_1113  8234
1_1113  9234
```

The keys of the hash correspond to the numbers in the left column, while the values are arrays of numbers from the right column. Now you can iterate through the hash and process it as you wish.

Comment: Thanks! but the reason that I want to process line by line is because the file is too big. This would work for a smaller file.